# jQuery Draggable and overflow issue

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am having an undesired effect when I drag a div from a container div which is set as overflow: scroll.

I have found an example of someone else where they have had the issue but I have been unable to find a resolution

[Example on Paste bin](http://pastebin.me/49c793a050bcd)

What happens is that the scroll is just increased, I can see why this would be the desired behaviour if you wanted to drag to a destination within the scrollable div but I want to be able to take it outside of its scrolling grasp.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It certainly pays to pay attention to the documentation

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-scroll

> #### scroll
>
> **Type:** Boolean
> **Default:** `true`
> If set to `true`, container auto-scrolls while dragging.

All who enter here, learn from my mistake, RT(F)M!!!

Comment: wasted 2 hours indeed. We should really RTFM

Comment: I had a similar problem with a accordion. I had a draggable inside an accordion panel and wanted to drag it outside the accordion, but the accordion panel had 'overflow' set to 'auto' and I never managed to get outside the accordion. Setting "scroll: false" on the accordion didn´t help.
In the end I overruled the overflow set in jquery-ui. This make the height of my content panel look strange, so I had to had wire a given height. And that worked.

Answer (score 111):

I had a similar problem enabling a drag between two overflow-auto divs.  With the help of the previous answers, I found that this combination works for me (Safari 5.0.3, jquery-1.4.4, jquery-ui-1.8.7):

```
appendTo: 'body',
containment: 'window',
scroll: false,
helper: 'clone'
```

Answer (score 56):

appendTo

Element, SelectorDefault:'parent'

The element passed to or selected by the appendTo option will be used as the draggable helper's container during dragging. By default, the helper is appended to the same container as the draggable.

Code examples
Initialize a draggable with the appendTo option specified.

```
$('.selector').draggable({ appendTo: 'body' });
```

Comment: I tried to do as you suggest but it is not changing it to the desired behaviour, when you add the code you mentioned into the example on the Paste bin page, does it work for you? Thanks

Comment: yeah, I totally fail on this question. I played with it for an hour. The best I can get is how I left it, draggable doesn't work with overflow :(

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your effort! :)

Comment: Yea, you just saved hours and my humiliation asking the local hot shot!

Comment: @EvoD -- chances are the local hotshot just gets his info here anyway.

Comment: Local hotshot here, I can confirm that I get all of my information from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 20):

The clone solution it works, but has two problems.

First: the clone are append to the body. Depending of your css, your element can change the styles, since before it starts, it's inside of another element and during the dragging, it will be directly on body element.

Second: Sometimes the element MUST move, and the clone let the object there.

So, the solution for this problems is:

```
$('.selector').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(){
        $(this).hide();             
    },
    stop: function(){
        $(this).show()
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! And thanks for the hint about the css - helped me to solve both issues.

Comment: To really mimic Draggable's 'original' behavior, you'd prefer to use the CSS property "visibility"

Answer (score 2):

Setting the scroll option does not stop children from being hidden in the overflow area. I have come up with a work-a-round that uses the helper option. Check it out:

http://pastebin.me/164f0a4073496563fe3179ddcec5fd6d

Also here is a reference to another post I made:

[jquery ui draggable elements not 'draggable' outside of scrolling div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098387/jquery-ui-draggable-elements-not-draggable-outside-of-scrolling-div/2099100#2099100)

Answer (score -1):

You can also specify which types of elements you don't want to include.

```
<div class="draggable"> 
    <h2>This will drag the div</h2>
    <ul>
       <li>This won't drag the div</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Apply this cancel property to ignore the event in specified child elements

```
$('.draggable').draggable({cancel : 'ul'});
```