# jQuery Ui: Cant drag element from Div with overflow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple UL in a div with the overflow set to automatic and a fixed height. Each LI is draggable via jQuery.
Problem is that I cannot drag them from the div (they disappear when dragged to the boundaries).

I have looked at this question and its answers, but the solution here does not seem to work for me (setting the scroll option):
[jQuery Draggable and overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811037/jquery-draggable-and-overflow-issue)

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got around this by using a helper method to append the item to the body (so its outside the div)

```
$("#myitem").draggable({
helper: function() { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show(); }
});
```

Not sure if you need the show() and I also had to raise the z-index but it depends on the rest of your page.

Phil

Comment: perfect. I did originally try the appendTo: 'body' option, which I would have thought would have the same effect, but didnt!

Comment: Glad to help, took me hours to figure this out too :)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to achieve the same results with

```
appendTo: 'body',
helper: 'clone'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar problem , where if once drags the component below out of the boundry of the page, it disappears.

to fixit I use the stop event of the draggable plugin, in the

```
$('.dragableComp').draggable({
   stop:function(){
        //here write the code for adjusting the top and left of your component
   },..
});
```