# jqueryUI: Drag element from dialog and drop onto main page?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to create a drag and drop system consisting of a workspace and a "palette". The workspace currently consists of re-orderable list items, and I want the palette to be a floating window from which I can drag items and add them to a specific position on the workspace.

I am currently using the **jqueryUI "sortable"** plugin for the workspace and the **jqueryUI "dialog"** plugin for the palette.

However, I cannot drag something *out of* the dialog and *on to* the main page. When I try, the item being dragged disappears as it crosses the boundary of the dialog (which makes sense). What can I change so that items will remain visible as I drag them out of the palette *and* allow me to drop them onto the main workspace?

Alternatively, are there any jquery plugins that offer this sort of drag-n-drop palette as a primary feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dragging items from the palette **duplicates them, without removing them from the palette**, then the answer is the `appendTo` option of the [draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-appendTo). This specifies the container to use during dragging. In my case I created a new div outside the bounds of the dialog and specified that as the dragging container. This allows the element to be drug beyond the bounds of the dialog window.

To ***move* items from the palette onto the workspace**, I used the techniques from this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098387/jquery-ui-draggable-elements-not-draggable-outside-of-scrolling-div).