# strange bug in jQueryUI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

i've found a bug in jQueryUI draggable.... check it out on their demo page [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/default.html)

if you drag the object down far enough so that the page scrolls downwards, the draggable object loses it's position relative to the cursor.

any ideas what's causing the bug, and how to remedy it?

thanks :)

Comment: duplicate issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811037/jquery-draggable-and-overflow-issue

Comment: And did you log a bug or look for a bug in their tracker?

Comment: It is not a bug. You need to specify the scroll option http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-scroll

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a scroll option :

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ scroll: true });
$( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ scroll: true, scrollSensitivity: 100 });
$( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ scroll: true, scrollSpeed: 100 });
```

check: [This Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#scroll)