# FullCalendar External Events in an overflow div

Tags: fullcalendar

We're using JQuery FullCalendar latest version with draggable option on. The external event div is filled with values from the database. The div height is limited. So we added overflow auto to the external event container div.

It created a glitch that makes the event invisible when dragging it on the calendar. It also created a glitch that makes both scroll bar appears when dragging the event off the external event container.

I realise we are probably using the wrong tool for the job. Is there a proper way to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to replicate this without code. Could you post yours?

Comment: @ganeshk, you can replicate it by adding overflow:auto to the external event div of the full calendar draggable demo.

Answer (score 0):

Its in fact more jquery draggable issue.

This code for external draggable events placed in div with *overflow: scroll* worked for me:

```
  $(element).draggable({
        scroll: false,
        helper: 'clone',
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0
    });
```

Check also [jQuery Draggable and overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811037/jquery-draggable-and-overflow-issue)