# dropping a draggable item from a div with 'overflow: scroll/auto' style applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/u22PD/69.
`Draggable` and `droppable` are initialized this way:

```
$lister.find('.draggable').draggable({
    stack: 'div'
});

$('#insert-editor .droppable-target').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html(ui.draggable);
    }
});
```

It is only possible to drag `.darggable` item over `#image-lister` div. How do I drop a `.draggable` item onto the `droppable-target`?

Also how to keep the `draggable` item after it's been dragged-dropped to the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution there: [jQuery Draggable and overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811037/jquery-draggable-and-overflow-issue)

Changed my code to this:

```
$lister.find('.draggable').draggable({
    scroll: false,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function() {
        $(this).hide();             
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).show()
    }
});
```

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/u22PD/91

The only thing that doesn't satisfy me is that you still can see as a draggable item goes under the hidden part of the parent division when dragged. Maybe you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: auto;` from  `#image-lister`

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/6rxje/)**

```
#image-lister { 
    position: relative; max-width: 1920px; min-width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;
    height: 530px;
    overflow: auto; /*remove this */
    background: #ddd;
    background: #555;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: But I really need a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: You might try {overflow-y: scroll} instead.